# Yodlee Not pulling Debig/Checking Recoreds, Only pulling Credit Card/Rewards Points/Bill Pay Records

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the Yodlee API and its pulling all the data I need including line item transactions for Credit Card/Rewards Points/Bill Pay etc.. but it's only giving a summary for my debit/checking transactions..

I need to be able to pull line item transactions for debit card and checking transactions as well..

I'm using Fast Link and it's showing that its linked as I'm able to pull balances, refresh dates etc.. but I'm unable to access the per transaction data I'm able to pull on the Credit Card accounts..

This works for Credit Card:

$trans_data_checking[5]['itemData']['accounts'][$b]['cardTransactions'][$i]['plainTextDescription']

But the 'cardTransactions' field doesn't occur for the checking/debit card accounts..

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yodlee has data model designed as per different types of banking products like bank accounts, credit card accounts, loan accounts, investment accounts and so on. In Yodlee's terminology all these different products are called as containers. Now each container has their own set of fields which are relevant to any type of accounts under that category. Now savings/Checking accounts comes under bank container and transactions belonging to these accounts will have field called bankTranasctions and hence you are not finding cardTransaction field for checking/debit card accounts.